# Sharing ABI between erc721/erc20 Tokens?

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, web3js

Say I have an ethereum contract that uses erc721 protocol.
When I create a new contract object using web3.

```
 const contract = new web3.eth.contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
```

Is it possible to include only the abi of the parent erc721 contract, aslong as I only use functions that are within the erc721 scope? Or does web3 require the full abi?

I want to know if I can call upon multiple erc721 tokens sharing one abi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a common ABI for multiple contracts. The limitation is that you'll be able to use only the methods and properties defined in the ABI.

And the other way around: If you call a method that is defined in the ABI but not in the actual contract, the contract will try to run the fallback function.

---

`web3` needs the ABI to be able to tell how to encode the function arguments and return values. So if you call `foo(1, 2)` should it encode as `foo(uint8 1, uint64 2)` or `foo(bool true, uint256 2)`?

But it's really "just" a helper to generate the correct functions in the `contract.methods.*` list and their encoding map. So if you don't need some of them, you can skip this by not defining them in the ABI.